# ./configure: No such file or directory while installing tar.gz

Tags: tar, configure, gzip

I am new to the Ubuntu. I tried to install `pycharm-community-5.0.tar.gz` with following command:

```
tar -xzf pycharm-community-5.0.tar.gz   
cd pycharm-community-5.0
./configure
```

it says

```
./configure: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Does the tarball actually contain source code? The one from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/) appears to be a pre-built binary package. Did you read the [installation instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/installation_instructions.jsp?os=linux)?

Comment: did you check available list of files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The archive `pycharm-community-5.0.tar.gz` doesn't contain a `configure`. Extract the archive and run PyCharm

```
sudo tar xf pycharm-community-5.0.tar.gz -C /opt
/opt/pycharm-community-5.0/bin/pycharm.sh
```

For a better integration in your desktop, create a desktop file:

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/pycharm.desktop
```

and add the configuration below

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=PyCharm
Exec=/opt/bin/pycharm.sh
Icon=/opt/bin/pycharm.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Development;
Keywords=ide;python;charm;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the below two options for installing pycharm in Ubuntu:

1. ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mystic-mirage/pycharm
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install pycharm
   ```
2. Follow the steps mentioned in this [link](http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/10/install-pycharm-on-ubuntu-linux/)

Comment: please delete your old answer before you receive more downvotes on it, this answer is better.